# JavaScript Time comparison between JSON and Localtime not working

Tags: javascript, json, time, compare

I am working with a JSON data that would look like this

```js
[
    {
        "hourly_AQI": 73.0,
        "hourly_date": "Tue, 31 Oct 2023 11:00:00 GMT"
    },
    {
        "hourly_AQI": 79.0,
        "hourly_date": "Tue, 31 Oct 2023 13:00:00 GMT"
    },
    {
        "hourly_AQI": 77.0,
        "hourly_date": "Tue, 31 Oct 2023 14:00:00 GMT"
    }
]
```

And I also got a code which will make an array that the hourly_date is greater than local current time. But when I use and run the code at 18:03 the code would give me the time from 13:00:00 onward as a result why is that?

```js
const now = new Date();
const filteredData = aqiData?.filter((item) => {  
    const date = new Date(item.hourly_date);
    // Check if the item's date is in the future
    return date >= now
});
console.log(filteredData)
```

I tried it at around 1 PM as well and it would give me a data from 7:00 am onward even I specify the code to give me greater or equal to. I'm confused please help!

Answer (score 0):

> 

```js
const now = new Date();
const localTimeZone = 'your-time-zone-here';

const formatter = new Intl.DateTimeFormat('en-US', { timeZone: localTimeZone, hour12: false });
const filteredData = aqiData?.filter((item) => {  
    const date = new Date(item.hourly_date);
    const formattedDate = formatter.format(date);

    return new Date(formattedDate) >= now;
});
console.log(filteredData);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can convert the now Date object to GMT before doing the comparison.
Here's how you can do that:

```
const now = new Date();
const nowInGMT = new Date(now.getUTCFullYear(), now.getUTCMonth(), now.getUTCDate(), now.getUTCHours(), now.getUTCMinutes(), now.getUTCSeconds());

const filteredData = aqiData?.filter((item) => {  
    const date = new Date(item.hourly_date);
    // Check if the item's date is in the future
    return date >= nowInGMT;
});
console.log(filteredData);
```